# Attempting to remove "www" and force "https" on domain and trying to make it do both

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
    #Remove www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
    RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    #force https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    #ignore folder for removing slash & removing .html
    RewriteRule ^(whmcs) - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

So this is my current code. Here is my results:

website.com --> https://website.com

http://website.com --> https://website.com

www.website.com --> https://website.com

http://www.website.com --> https://website.com

All good except...

https://www.website.com --> https://www.website.com <--No good.

I have been researching and attempting to rewrite this to no success. Please any help and if you would be so kind to leave documentation so I could read further. Either way I need a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have written so many re-writing conditions to `remove www` and `force https`. If they not any other specific needs then you can just try this simple solution

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    #ignore folder for removing slash & removing .html
    RewriteRule ^(whmcs) - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 

If this is what you meant it still did not solve the issue.

Comment: @AndrewFair are you still viewing `https://www.website.com` ? have you tried after clearing browser cache completely ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, here is how i fixed it.

```
### WWW & HTTPS

#Remove WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### WWW & HTTPS
```

Comment: I tried this and got the exact same results. 

https://www.website.com/ does not redirect to https://website.com.